# What is the best way to achieve DevOps in any environment, or it is always environment dependent?

Tags: culture

I want to know that is there possibility to make DevOps generic, and not environment specific, so that can be used with any project with same cases OR we can cover common cases with one time code.
Though language and environment changes but the logic remains same for most of the Test cases based on..

I know every organization follows different methodology, I am assuming here that We will use one standard methodology and One standard Development culture.

1. Run environment
2. Development Culture, etc.

I want to achieve Common DevOps environment that can be used for any project for common cases. Only special cases need to be handled separately.

Have anyone achieved this?

I know this is little broad question, but we this is DevOps related only.

Comment: You should specify what you put under 'Devops' this sounds like a word bag here and as such very unclear. DevOps is a culture, that has nothing to do with programmatic language, it involves using automation in term of continuous integration and continuous deployment but as is your question is very unclear on what you're after.

Comment: @Tensibai I have edited question, but still I am looking for some way where I can use common test cases for integration in any project any any point of time.

Comment: That's not really clearer what you're talking about, is it Unit tests ?

Comment: I suspect this is going to be opinion-based, there are various "models" for DevOps such as Gene Kim's 3-Ways, Google's Site Reliability Engineering and Werner Vogel's "You Build It, You Run It" - the thing to note about all three though is they don't speak to technology at all, but people and process - i.e. they are culture-centric not technology-centric.

Comment: @RichardSlater I will look into Gene Kim's ways, that looks like helpful information! thanks for that. Can we automate one of the culture?

Comment: DevOps Adoption is often described in terms of Culture, Automation, Lean, Measurement and Sharing (CALMS) - Automation is a "first-class citizen" within DevOps alongside Culture, a DevOps transformation would aim to introduce these five aspects of DevOps into an organisation.  Culture is not something that you can automate, it's not a technology and it doesn't come with an API, culture is about how people think and relate to each other to approach work.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question about what is DevOps?

DevOps both involves Strategy and Tactics.

Strategy embraces building a culture centered around collaboration in your software development, technical operations and any other group or organization that has a stake in the deliverables whether it's software or service.

Examples of DevOps strategy may be breaking down silos, continuous delivery, continuous integration, etc.

Tactics are the actual implementation of the strategies.

This is the level where the use of software tools, technology and management methods are found as well as the actual "how to".  For instance, to foster "breaking down of silos" as a tactic, you build smaller "agile" teams of 5-7 "stakeholders" let's say programmers, systems admins, QA engineer, and a project manager.  To communicate among the team members, you use Slack.  Programmers and sysadmins "cross train" on each others tasks where it makes sense.  Sysadmins may assist in developing test harnesses for the programmers, use Selenium and python for testing.  Programmers learn how to use Ansible and assist the Sysadmins on what they need in the development and production environment.

Where you sound like your at is looking at all these cool tactics and tools that DevOps uses such as Docker, Ansible, Chef but your missing the understanding of Strategy...building of the culture, the "why" you want to use these tactics and tools.  That's ok, we're here to learn.

There is no "right" answer on what exactly DevOps is or how you implement it, but in all the talks and examples of DevOps shops and organization it boils down to the strategy of building a collaborating organization and focusing on a purpose then put it into action as tactics.